# How to get a Telerik/Kendo's DropDownListFor's SelectedIndex?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, selectedindex, dropdownlistfor

My view file defines the control like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(e => e.ExportSpecID)
    .BindTo(ViewBag.ExportSpecList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
    .OptionLabel(" ")
    .Events(e => e.Change("SelectExistingChange"))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbSelectExisting", searchField = "ExportSpecID", @class = "k-dropdown-width-200" }).Enable(false))
```

In my Javascript function, I need to get the index of the selected item. I've found a variety of similar questions on StackOverflow, and implemented each solution:

```
var cmbSI = $("#cmbSelectExisting").selectedIndex;
var selectedIndex1 = $("#cmbSelectExisting option:selected").index();
var selectedIndex2 = $("select[name='cmbSelectExisting'] option:selected").index();
```

But these do not yield the correct value:

[image]

I suspect it has something to do with these Telerik controls / the way I wire up the event handler, but I couldn't find another question trying to get the value via javascript/jquery using these controls. So does anyone know how I can get the SelectedIndex for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
var selectedIndex = $('#cmbSelectExisting').data('kendoDropDownList').selectedIndex;
```